# Angular-Material set a Datepicker with only months and years

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular 1.5.9 & angular material design 1.1.1

I would like to add a Datepicker with months and years only, no days, it's for a credit card expiration field in a checkout form.

Comment: for angular material datepicker with month and years visit https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Answer (score 2):

You can set `md-mode="month"` working demo below

```
   <md-input-container flex="100" layout="column">
          <div style="font-size: 10px; color: blue;" label ng-bind="::dateFields[2].label"></div>
          <md-datepicker ng-model="dateFields.selectedDate"
                     ng-required="dateFields.required"
                     md-date-locale="dateFields.locale"
                     md-mode="month"
                     md-open-on-focus="true">
        </md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/eV2Kmt?p=preview)**

Comment: maybe put `md-mode="month"` inline in the code snippet instead as a variable? I think it might be clearer

Comment: it's not. currently, it's `md-mode="{{dateFields[2].mode}}"`.
If it was a simple use instead of variable base, it might be easier for people to understand

Comment: @Thatkookooguy its good if you can upvote the answer instead of comment :P

Comment: In your plunker, it is working only by using:

https://static.formhero.io/formhero/js/material/v1.1.1-fh-build/angular-material.min.js

It is not working, if i have used :

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js

Can you please let me know.

Here is my plunker link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/i5Zo32H2kZIbFvMuBwTc?p=preview

Comment: I also tried, but its not working. Ur example also in plunkar only its working If i download and run the same code its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing, that `md-mode="month"` isn't working in latest versions, like 7.3.7, i have other solution. 
First in your component HTML put this (includes input for showing selected month + input which will be hidden, but needed for mat-datepicker):

```
<input type="text" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pickerDate" placeholder="Choose a date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker startView="year" [startAt]="pickerDate" (monthSelected)="closeDatePicker($event)"></mat-datepicker>
```

Then in your ts file put these lines:

```
private pickerDate;
@ViewChild('picker') datePicker: MatDatepicker<any>;

closeDatePicker(event) {
    this.pickerDate = moment(event).format('YYYY-MM');
    this.datePicker.close();
}
```

And that's it. Inputs now should work. Also i used this css for hidden input hiding:

```
input[matinput] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Keep in mind, that you shouldn't use hidden on matInput, else datepicker popup will show in wrong position. If you use my css, keep in mind, that matInput parent should have `position: relative`!

Answer (score 0):

For Angular Material datepicker with month and years --

`app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var monthFormat =  buildLocaleProvider("MMM-YYYY");

    function buildLocaleProvider(formatString) {
        return {
            formatDate: function (date) {
                if (date) return moment(date).format(formatString);
                else return null;
            },
            parseDate: function (dateString) {
                if (dateString) {
                    var m = moment(dateString, formatString, true);
                    return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
                }
                else return null;
            }
        };
    }


  $scope.dateFields = [ 
                {
                    type: 'date',
                    required: false,
                    binding: 'applicant.expectedGraduation',
                    startView: 'month',
                    label: 'Credit Card Expiry - Year/Month picker',
                    mode: 'month',
                    locale: monthFormat
                }
    ];
});
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS material-sidenav Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.formhero.io/formhero/js/material/v1.1.1-fh-build/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://static.formhero.io/formhero/js/material/v1.1.1-fh-build/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body layout="row" layout-wrap flex layout-fill layout-align="start start" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <md-input-container flex="100" layout="column">
          <div style="font-size: 10px; color: blue;" label ng-bind="::dateFields[0].label"></div>
          <md-datepicker ng-model="dateFields[0].selectedDate"
                     ng-required="dateFields[0].required"
                     md-date-locale="dateFields[0].locale"
                     md-mode="{{dateFields[0].mode}}"
                     md-open-on-focus="true">
        </md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
</body>

</html>
```

For a demonstration use below link--
https://plnkr.co/edit/zXhgq3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the [documentation here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#watching-the-views-for-changes-on-selected-years-and-months) for **angular 8**.

Don't forget to set the formControl with a Moment, for ex: `this.monthlyResportDateFormControl = new FormControl(moment(this.monthlyReportDate))`

Getting the value into `chosenMonthHandler` I did it with `this.monthlyReportDate = this.monthlyResportDateFormControl.value.toDate()`